# Issue with Android intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have created an Intent filter to open my application when clicking on an specified link such as "http://www.myapp.com/1234". When I click on the link I am asked to open the app, and OK, everything works well. Then, I quit from the app by clicking repeatedly in the back button until all activities are closed. But:

1. After launching the app again from the launcher, it receives the same Intent data than 
   before when I clicked the link. How do avoid it?
2. When I open my app from a link, ie. from WhatsApp, as I can see in the app manager, WhatsApp is the application which is opened! why?

Here is my current manifest code:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.x.y.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="@string/app_host"
                android:pathPrefix="/events/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in my `onCreate()`:

```
    // Retrieve the Intent
    Intent intentUri = getIntent();

    // Check URI
    Uri uri = intentUri.getData();

    if (uri != null) {
        // Try to extract the data
        // For now, data could be a public event id, so parse it
        List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();

        // Check validity
        if (pathSegments.size() > 2) {
            // Finally, get the public event id
            String publicEventId = pathSegments.get(2);

            // Set poll as responded
            user.setPollEventId(publicEventId);
        }

        // Remove the intent to prevent further calls
        setIntent(null);
    }

    // Open the main activity normally
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: regarding 2. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html your activity becomes part of the WhatsApp task. Linked page mentions several things you can control (in the manifest mostly) how your Activity should interact with tasks, how it should be started etc. E.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear sounds interesting, I have no Idea whether that's what you need though.

Comment: Why have you got `android:noHistory="true"`?

Comment: I use `android:noHistory="true"` because, since it is a splash screen, I do not want to come back to that activity once I close the main activity (main comes after splash).

Comment: Are you saying that when you launch the app again from the HOME screen, in `onCreate()` a call to `getIntent()` returns an `Intent` with ACTION=VIEW and the URI in the DATA?

Comment: ahá, that's it! and I'm going crazy

Comment: Please post some code from your `onCreate()`

Comment: I've just tested this myself an it works correctly. The first time it gets called with an `Intent` containing ACTION=VIEW. The second time (when I launch the app from the HOME screen), it gets an `Intent` containing ACTION=MAIN. You are doing something else strange.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. What you might try is to separate the LAUNCH activity from the BROWSE activity. Create a new activity that has the `<intent-filter>` for the URL. In `onCreate()` of that activity, just start the `SplashActivity` and pass the URL as an EXTRA. See if that helps.

Comment: Oh my god!!! I was wrong, the problem wasn't in the Intent, some global object was not destroyed and that was the reason of my problem. Sorry for that and THANK YOU SO MUCH for your answers!!

Comment: So why was this incorrect answer accepted? This is not good for other people who have this same problem and see your question and follow the accepted (but incorrect answer). My suggestion is that you delete your question because it has more harmful information in it than good information. If you can't delete it, flag it and request that the moderators delete it.

Comment: Did you have a static member? This might explain why the activity is not destroyed when pressing back. I can't seem to delete my answer as it's already accepted. If you unaccept, I'll delete it.